# Gracefully shutdown when using npm-run-all

Tags: node.js, nodemon, concurrently

In my development environment, I am using `npm-run-all` (`run-p`) to run two npm scripts in parallel: the typescript compiler in wach mode; and my server with nodemon. I am trying to gracefully shutdown my server when I hit `CTRL+C`, but it seems that the neither `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM` are being captured. Can anyone identify what is the problem?

I am using Node v18.3.0 on Windows, `npm-run-all@^4.1.5` and `nodemon@^2.0.20`.

(I also tried using `concurrently`, but had the same issue...)

*package.json*:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node --enable-source-maps ./dist/index.js",
    "dev": "npm run build && run-p dev:*",
    "dev:build": "tsc -w",
    "dev:run": "nodemon ./dist/index.js"
  }
```

*./dist/index.js*:

```typescript
const shutdown = () => {
    httpServer.stop()
    socketServer.stop()
}

process.once('SIGINT', shutdown)
process.once('SIGTERM', shutdown)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NPM swallows the SIGTERM/SIGINT signals](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4603), so to gracefuly shutdown your app do not use `npm run` but `node` itself

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, does it mean it is impossible to do this in a package.json script? Or do I just need to change the `npm run` in my script to a node equilavent command?

Comment: Using node instead of npm should do the trick

Comment: Do not use npm scripts unless you have another way to trigger the shutdown, like capturing a key combination or receiving a command